# How to get previous year using vb.net or c#.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

guys

I have the input date is this  : 10/11/2020
and my output should be : 10/11/ 2019

how to do this using vb.net or C#.net

Comment: Is your "input" a `string` or a `DateTime`?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it's a string format

Comment: You can get a paper and a pen and write down your ideas, to get your algorithm

Comment: var date = DateTime.Parse(datestring).AddYears(-1)

Comment: My preferred way: 1) parse the string to a `DateTime`. 2) use `.AddYears(-1)` to get last year. 3) use `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` or `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` to get a string output for the new date. Alternative: do some complex string manipulation stuff to edit the string itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dateadd function

```
Dim d As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Cdate("10/11/2020"))
Msgbox(Format(d, "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Or as the comments say, you can use AddYears

```
Dim d As Date = Cdate("10/11/2020").AddYears(-1)
Msgbox(Format(d, "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: thanks a lot it's perfectly worked

Comment: @TapanBehera The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is by accepting their answer. Do this by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will help future readers, give the answerer some reps and give you 2 points.